# Why is this never the square of a number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be an inteteger. Why is $6n+2$ never a square of a integer $m$? 
If $n$ and $m$ would be real numbers the problem would be easy. How do I prove that?

Comment: Squares mod $3$ are $\equiv \{0,1,2\}^2\equiv \{0,1\}\,$ so are not $\equiv 2\pmod3\ \ $

Answer (score 4):

If $6n+2=m^2$, then $m^2 \equiv 2 \pmod 3$. But no square is $2$ modulo $3$ ($0^2 \equiv 0$, $1^2\equiv 1$, $2^2\equiv 1$)

Answer (score 1):

There are $3$ types of nonnegative integers, those who give a remainder $1$ when divided by $3$ (they can be written as $3k+1$ with $k$ a nonnegative integer), those who give a remainder of $2$, (they can be written as $3k+2$ with $k$ a nonnegative integer) and those who give a remainder of $0$.

Because $(-n)^2=n^2$, the set of nonnegative integers is enough to form all perfect squares, and hence all perfect squares are of the form:

$$(3k+1)^2$$

$$(3k+2)^2$$

$$(3k)^2$$

Or equivalently,

$$9k^2+6k+1$$

$$9k^2+12k+4$$

$$9k^2$$

Note how $9k^2$ is divisible by $3$ as $9$ is so, in that case when $9k^2$ is divided by $3$ it leaves remainder $0$. And when $9k^2+12k$ or $9k^2+6k$ are divided by $3$ they also leave remainder $0$, so for the first two forms above $9k^2+6k+1$ and $9k^2+12k+1$ we are left with a remainder of $1$.

Hence a perfect square only leaves remainder of $0$ or $1$ when divided by $3$. But $6k+2$ leaves a remainder of $2$.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$
k^2 \bmod 6 = ((k \bmod 6) (k\bmod 6)) \bmod 6 \in \{0, 1, 3, 4 \}
$$
where it suffices to try out $k \in \{0,\dotsc, 5\}$.

The result set shows that $6n+2$ and $6n+5$ can not show up.